# Is there a way to up only security context in Spring Boot tests?

Tags: spring-security, spring-test, spring-boot-test, spring-security-test

I want to write some kind of unit test which depends on Spring Security.

For example, I have some service method which uses some repository and marked with @PreAuthorize annotation. Repository I can mock with Mockito, there is no problem. Also I can mock Security Context by [@WithSecurityContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withsecuritycontext) annotation. But when I run test, the @PreAuthorize annotation is just ignored. Of course I can run that test with @SpringBootTest annotation as an integration test and in this case the Security Context is up but this way is heavy and slow.

Is there a way to run unit test with **only** Spring Security Context raised?

**UPDATE**

Made an example of such kind of test. Thanks to @Sam Brannen for giving right direction.

```
@ActiveProfiles("method-security-test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ExampleService.class, ExampleServiceTest.MethodSecurityConfiguration.class})
public class ExampleServiceTest {

    private ExampleService service;

    @Autowired
    public void setService(ExampleService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "john_doe")
    public void testAuthenticated() {
        String actualMessage = service.example();
        Assert.assertEquals("Message of john_doe", actualMessage);
    }

    @Test(expected = AuthenticationException.class)
    public void testNotAuthenticated() {
        service.example();
        Assert.fail();
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    static class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    }
}

@Service
class ExampleService {
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    String example() {
        Principal principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return "Message of " + principal.getName();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@PreAuthorize` annotation from Spring Security will only be honored if Spring Security proxies your component (e.g., service bean).

The simplest way to make that happen is by annotating an `@Configuration` class with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`, having your component registered as a bean (e.g., via component scanning or an `@Bean` method), and including your `AuthenticationManager` setup.

You can then create a focused integration test using `@ContextConfiguration` (without Spring Boot testing support) to load an `ApplicationContext` from your `@Configuration` class. And you can use `@Autowired` to get access to your proxied component which will be advised with the `@PreAuthorize` security check support.

You might find this old blog post useful as well for background information: https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/

Comment: Can anyone provide an example of this?

Comment: There's an example in the UPDATE section of the original question above.

Comment: oh my bad I was in rush, thanks